# Javascript works for one of my html pages externally but does not work externally with the other pages (works internally with other pages)

Tags: javascript, html

For the html pages where the external javascript does not work, I put the js code in  internally in the HTML file and it worked but what's the problem with the pages that can't do it without applying javascript in the HTML pages. The only page it works externally is in contact.html below. After that code is the sample1.html file where it does not work externally but only internally? What can I do to make it work externally? (javascript file is in the same folder)

```
contact.html
` <!--contact us page-->
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheet.css"> <!--link stylesheet-->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css"> <!--link external icons-->
<link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">       <!--link external fonts-->
<link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Open+Sans:wght@300&display=swap" rel="stylesheet"> 

<title id="title">Contact Us</title>
</head>
<body>
       <!--header--> 
       <section class="header3">
        <nav>
           
           <a href="sample1.html"><img src="images/classpass.png"></a>
           <div class="nav-links" id="navLinks">
        <i class="fa fa-times" onclick="hideMenu()"></i>       
     
      <ul>
            <li><a  href="sample2.html">Sponsor Us</a></li>
            <li><a class="active" href="sample1.html">About</a></li>
            <li><a href="contact.html">Contact Us</a></li>
            <li><a href="https://kidshelpphone.ca/">Kids Help Phone</a></li>
            <li><img src="images/moon.png" id="icon2"></li>
          </ul>
          
        </div>
        <i class="fa fa-bars" onclick="showMenu()"></i> 
        </nav>
    
    <div class="text-box">
        <h1>Contact Us</h1> 
    </div>
    </section>

<!--inquiry box  inspired from w3schools.com-->
<section class="box">
        <div class="row">
        <div class="box-col">
<form action="/action_page.php">
  <div class="container">
    <h1>Have Any Inquires?</h1>
    <p>Fill out the form and our team will get back to you as soon as possible</p>
  </div>

  <div class="container" style="background-color:white">
    <input type="text" id="inquiry"placeholder="Inquiry" name="name" required>
    <p class="rq">*Required Field </p>
    <input type="text" id="email2" placeholder="Email address" name="mail" required>
    <p class="rq">*Required Field </p>
  </div>

  <div class="container">
    <button type="submit" id="button1">Submit</button>
  </div>
</form>
</div>
<div class="box-col">
    <form name="form1" action="/action_page.php" onsubmit="required"()>
      <div class="container">
        <h1>Get A Estimated Quote</h1>
        <p>This is just a estimate and our team will send a email with more detailed information</p>
      </div>
    
      <div class="container" style="background-color:white">
        <input type="text"  id="text" placeholder="Name" name="name3" required>
        <p class="rq">*Required Field </p>
        <input type="text"  id="email" placeholder="Email address" name="mail3" required>
        <p class="rq">*Required Field </p>
        <input type="text" id="classNum" placeholder="How many different classrooms would you need" name="classrooms3" required>
        <p class="rq">*Required Field </p>
      </div>
    
      <div class="container">
        <button type="submit"  id="button">Submit</button>
      </div>
    </form>
    </div>

</div>
</section>

<!--end-->

   <!-- offices(portion)-->
   <section class="portion">
    <h1>Our Offices</h1>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="portion-col">
            <img src="images/city1.jpg">
            <h3>Toronto Hub</h3>
            <div class="phone">
                <i class="fa fa-phone"></i>
                <i><a href="">4164506779</a></i>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="portion-col">
            <img src="images/city2.jpg">
            <h3>Montreal Hub</h3>
            <div class="phone">
                <i class="fa fa-phone"></i>
                <i><a href="">4164506779</a></i>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="portion-col">
            <img src="images/city3.jpg">
            <h3>Brampton Hub</h3>
            <div class="phone">
                
                    <i class="fa fa-phone"></i>
                    <i><a href="">4164506779</a></i>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
</section>


<!--contact/support button-->
<section class="contact">
    <h1>About Us</h1>
    <br>
    <br>
    <a  href="sample1.html" class="button">Learn More</a>
    
    
    </section>
    

<!--footer-->
<section class="footer">
    <h4>ClassPass An Interactive Classroom</h4>
    <div class="icon">
        <i class="fa fa-twitter"></i>
        <i class="fa fa-youtube"></i>
        <i class="fa fa-facebook"></i>
        <i class="fa fa-linkedin"></i>
        <i class="fa fa-instagram"></i>
    </div>
<p>Made by Jashan Judge</p>
</section>
<script src="javascript.js"></script>
</body>
</html>` </strike>
```

sample1.html page that doesn't work externally

```
<!--about us page-->
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
   
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheet.css">  <!--link stylesheet-->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">  <!--link external icons-->
<link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">  <!--link external fonts-->
<link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Open+Sans:wght@300&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">

 <title id="title">ClassPass An Interactive Classroom</title>
</head>
<body>
    <!--header--> 
    <section class="header">
        <nav>
           
          <a href="sample1.html"><img src="images/classpass.png"></a>
          
           <div class="nav-links" id="navLinks" >
        <i class="fa fa-times" onclick="hideMenu()"></i>       
     
      <ul>
            <li><a  href="sample2.html">Support Us</a></li>
            <li><a class="active" href="sample1.html">About</a></li>
            <li><a href="contact.html">Contact Us</a></li>
            <li><a href="https://kidshelpphone.ca/">Kids Help Phone</a></li>
            <li><img src="images/moon.png" id="icon2"></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
        <i class="fa fa-bars" onclick="showMenu()"></i> 
        </nav>
    
    <div class="text-box">
        <h1>Class Pass</h1> 
        <p>An Interactive Classroom</p>
    </div>
    </section>
    
       
       <script>
        var navLinks = document.getElementById("navLinks");

        function showMenu(){
            navLinks.style.right = "0";
        }
            function hideMenu(){
            navLinks.style.right = "-200px";
    }
    </script>


<script>
var icon2 = document.getElementById("icon2");
 
if(localStorage.getItem("theme") == null){
   localStorage.setItem("theme", "light");
}


let localData = localStorage.getItem("theme");

if(localData=="light"){
   icon2.src== "images/moon.png";
   document.body.classList.remove("dark-mode");
}
else if(localData=="dark"){
   icon2.src== "iamges/sun.png";
   document.body.classList.add("dark-mode");
}

icon2.onclick = function(){
   document.body.classList.toggle("dark-mode");
   if(document.body.classList.contains("dark-mode")){
       icon2.src="images/sun.png";
       localStorage.setItem("theme","dark");
   }
   else{
       icon2.src="images/moon.png";
       localStorage.setItem("theme","light");
   }
}

</script>







<!--sideblock-->
<section class="sideblock">

    <div class="row">
        <div class="side-col">     
        <h1>Our Mission</h1>
        
        <p>Here at Class Pass we wanted to bring the classroom into the homes of students and teachers. We re-imagined the way students can interact with their classmates and teachers away from school. ClassPass is designed to offer students a wide varity of learning material through artifical intelligence based reccomended resources. At Class Pass we believe the future starts with the classroom. Important features: </p>

        <div class="list">
    <ul>
        <br>
        <li>AI Powered Resources</li>
        <br>
        <li>Interactive Online Community</li>
        <br>
        <li>Direct Communication To Teachers</li>
    </ul>
</div>
</div>

    <div class="side-col">
        
        <img src="images/class1.jpg">
    </div>
    </div>
</section>

<!-- sub moving cards-->
<section class="sub">
    <h1>Specififc features</h1>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="sub-col">
            <img src="images/infopic1.png">
            <div class="layer">
                <h3>AI Powered Resources</h3>
                <p>Class Pass uses the power of Artifical Intelligence to curate specialized resources to each student and teacher</p>
            </div>
    </div>
    <div class="sub-col">
        <img src="images/infopic2.jpg">
        <div class="layer">
            <h3>Interactive Online Community</h3>
            <p>Students can communicate with their classmates and interact with cards work together</p>
        </div>
</div>
<div class="sub-col">
    <img src="images/infopic3.jpg">
    <div class="layer">
        <h3>Direct Communication To Teachers</h3>
        <p>Parents and students can ask their teachers any questions anytime of the day</p>
    </div>
</div>
 </div>
</section>

<!--contact/support button-->
<section class="contact">
<h1>Interested In Our Vision?</h1>
<br>
<br>
<a  href="sample2.html" class="button">Support Us</a>
<a href="contact.html" class="button">Contact Us</a>

</section>

<!--footer-->
<section class="footer">
    <h4>ClassPass An Interactive Classroom</h4>
    <div class="icon">
        <i class="fa fa-twitter"></i>
        <i class="fa fa-youtube"></i>
        <i class="fa fa-facebook"></i>
        <i class="fa fa-linkedin"></i>
        <i class="fa fa-instagram"></i>
    </div>
<p>Made by Jashan Judge</p>
</section>
 
<script src="javascript.js"></script>
</body>
</html> </strike>
```

Comment: Is The Javascript In The Same Folder as that of the second file? Also why have you used strike at the start and end of this webpage?

Comment: @mrtechtroid it is in the same folder, I’m new to stack overflow lol I put it in by mistake on the website but it’s not like that in my actual code